# ggplot add text to the center of a donut chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, data-visualization, donut-chart

I am working on a donut chart using ggplot2, but I need the center of the plot to contain text.

Here's sample data (found from this site: https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-create-a-pie-chart-in-r-using-ggplot2/):

```
library(dplyr)
count.data <- data.frame(
  class = c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "Crew"),
  n = c(325, 285, 706, 885),
  prop = c(14.8, 12.9, 32.1, 40.2)
)
count.data <- count.data %>%
  arrange(desc(class)) %>%
  mutate(lab.ypos = cumsum(prop) - 0.5*prop)
count.data
```

I then modified their code to get this donut chart:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mycols <- c("#0073C2FF", "#EFC000FF", "#868686FF", "#CD534CFF")

ggplot(count.data, aes(x = 2, y = prop, fill = class)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0)+
  geom_text(aes(y = lab.ypos, label = paste0("n = ", n, ", \n", prop, "%")), color = "white")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycols) +
  theme_void() +
  xlim(.5, 2.5)
```

The plot looks like this:

[image]

It is exactly what I want except I need the center of the donut to have the proportion from a variable. In this case, I want the center to say 40.2% (the prop of crew, in this example).

How do I do this?

Comment: I would use `geom_text(aes(0.5, 0, label = max(count.data$prop)), data.frame(class = NA))`

Comment: @PoGibas, thanks for this suggestion! However, the real dataset that I'm using changes frequently, so Crew may not always be the max. How do I change this to be focused on Crew? I'm nervous to use its position because that can change as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Edit

Used annotate as suggested by @aosmith and made it a direct call to crew.

---

like this?

```r
ggplot(count.data, aes(x = 2, y = prop, fill = class)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0)+
  geom_text(aes(y = lab.ypos, label = paste0("n = ", n, ", \n", prop, "%")), color = "white")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycols) +
  theme_void() +
  xlim(.5, 2.5) +
  annotate(geom = 'text', x = 0.5, y = 0, label = paste0(count.data$prop[count.data$class == 'Crew'], "%"))
```

[image]

Comment: this is great! Is there any way to call out crew directly instead of its position? The real dataset that I'm working with changes frequently, so I'd feel more comfortable if it could call it by name. Thank you again!

Comment: You may want `annotate()` here.  `geom_text()` repeatedly prints the text as many times as there are rows in the dataset, which leads to the text looking "blurry".

Comment: @aosmith, I'm open to that, but how would I use annotate to get it to say 40.2% in this case? I've never used annotate before.

Comment: @J.Sabree, I hope this is what you meant with calling it by name and works for you.

Comment: @Max, yes 100%, thank you! I accepted your response as the answer and upvoted it. Thanks again!

Comment: @MaxTeflon How would you apply this for multiple doughnut charts in facets?